# Sliding drawer at bottom is not opening

Tags: android, scrollview, slidingmenu

I am creating one app,in my app i have set some of textview inside scrollview,i set sliding drawer at bottom to open,but the issue is sliding drawer is not opening completely..following is my snippet code of UI..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="Product Details"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleBrand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/brand" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/desc_name"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
                  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleBrand"
                  android:text="sdffdfs"
                  android:textSize="16dp" />

           </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

             <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleForm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/form_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="116dp"
                android:text="sdffdfs"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

             <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleMrp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mrp" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/desc_mrp"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_marginRight="116dp"
                 android:text="sdffdfs"
                 android:textSize="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

             <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titlePacking"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/packing" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_packing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titlePacking"
                android:text="sdffdfs"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

             <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleCompany"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/company" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_comp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleCompany"
                android:text="sdffdfs"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

             <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleWithBrand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/with_brand" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/desc_withbrnd"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleWithBrand"
               android:text="sdffdfs"
               android:textSize="16dp" />

           </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

             <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleStrength"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/strength" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/desc_strength"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleStrength"
     android:text="sdffdfs" />

</RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >   

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleContent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/content" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/desc_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleContent"
                 android:text="sdffdfs"
                 android:textSize="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/divider" />


        </LinearLayout>




    </ScrollView>
         <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Handle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#00FF00">

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="Bottom to Top" />

            <CheckBox 
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Jelly Bean"
            android:textSize="17dp"
                />

        <CheckBox 
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Ice Cream Sandwich"
            android:textSize="17dp"
                />

        <CheckBox 
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="HoneyComb"
            android:textSize="17dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add java code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this library

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

it is from the umano app, that has released some code.

Or

in your existing code remove  **android:layout_marginTop="150dp"** this line from Sliding Drawer your issue is solve.

Below is code for cover slide drawer more than half screen :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="Product Details"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleBrand"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Brand" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleBrand"
                    android:text="sdffdfs"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleForm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="form" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/form_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="116dp"
                    android:text="sdffdfs"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleMrp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="map" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc_mrp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="116dp"
                    android:text="sdffdfs"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titlePacking"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="packing" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc_packing"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titlePacking"
                    android:text="sdffdfs"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleCompany"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Company" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc_comp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleCompany"
                    android:text="sdffdfs"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleWithBrand"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bransd" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc_withbrnd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleWithBrand"
                    android:text="sdffdfs"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleStrength"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Strength" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc_strength"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleStrength"
                    android:text="sdffdfs" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleContent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleContent"
                    android:text="sdffdfs"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Handle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Bottom to Top"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Jelly Bean"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Ice Cream Sandwich"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="HoneyComb"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes its working some how..but can you tell what if i want to cover not full but more than half screen when i open drawer..

Comment: hi, i have update my answer using above xml you can open drawer more than half screen